# Function calling multiple times in d3 csv

Tags: reactjs, csv, d3.js, react-hooks

I need to handle the data from a csv file and used d3 csv in react.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CsvFile from './sentiment.csv'
import { csv } from 'd3'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  csv(CsvFile).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

data is not saving in the state variable properly
I guess because of this, I am not able to use react hooks to save the data I get from the csv file

[Array is shown twice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9koZ.png)

Comment: Share full code, please.

Comment: Add console log before `csv(CsvFile).then...` - I suppose it's called twice as well

Comment: You are calling `csv` method in `App` component body, so everytime `App` re-render `csv` method will execute. When do you want `csv` method to be called? On first render ?

Comment: yes @GulamHussain . But I only rendered it once, but it is showing twice

Comment: The code that you have shared will not run twice if App is not being re-rendered multiple times. can you please create a [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/)